# Sort List<int> based on order of List<string>

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I am having trouble figuring out a way to get this to work properly.  I have a list of integers.. and those integers are a count for the strings in my list of strings.

I am using MVC chart helper and my problem is that my `yValues` don't line up correctly with my `xValues`.

For example, my `List<string>` holds the values: `"Beginner"`, `"MOTR"`, `"Advanced"`. I use this list to order the list below.

And my database holds a bunch of records, and each record is either a `"Beginner"`, `"MOTR"`, or `"Advanced"`. so I have a foreach loop to gather the count for each of those Levels, so it can be dynamic.  But when the foreach loop executes it puts the Levels in alphabetical order.

I also have a class called `Rank` that has a property for the level (for partial view purposes)

Here is what I have:

```
List<string>lstLevelsInOrder = new List<string> {"Beginner", "MOTR", "Advanced"};

List<int> emptyListIntegers = new List<int>();
List<string> lstLevels = database.testdb.Where(x => x.deleted == false).Select(x => x.Level).Distinct().ToList();

foreach(var item in lstLevels)
{
    Rank rank = new Rank();
    rank.level = item;
    emptyListIntegers.Add(database.testdb.Where(x => x.Level == rank.level && x.deleted == false).Count());
}

var key = new Chart(width: 800, height: 800, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
    .SetXAxis()
    .SetYAxis()
    .AddTitle()
    .AddSeries(
    xValue: lstLevelsInOrder,
    yValues: emptyListIntegers
    );

return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
```

So just argument's sake let's say that the count for Beginner is 10, MOTR is 20, and Advanced is 5.

When that foreach loop executes the `emptyListIntegers` will be populated as 5, 10, 20 (due to alphabetical order)

so when i see my chart.. the x-axis is "Beginner" with a y-value of 5, "MOTR" with a y-value of 10, "Advanced" with a y-value of 20.

How do sort my `emptyListIntegers` based on the `lstLevelsInOrder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to order appropriately by the index of the `string` in the other list:

```
List<string> lstLevels = database.testdb
    .Where(x => ! x.deleted )
    .AsEnumerable()  // force Linq-To-Objects
    .OrderBy(x => lstLevelsInOrder.IndexOf(x.Level))
    .Select(x => x.Level)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: when I try this, I get to the .OrderBy and .IndexOf and when I try to put x.Level I am unable to.  I can't see my property names.. I get all of the methods.. but no property names

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: of course, you are selecting the strings before the distinct, i've fixed my answer now

Comment: got it now haha you rock man! thank you so much!